# I want to get different video streams in iOS player

Tags: ios, m3u8

I'm using M3U8Parser, but i'm getting exception while execution.

```
NSString *plainString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
infolist = [M3U8Parser m3u8SegmentInfoListFromPlanString:plainString];
```

After infolist,i'm getting exception.

```
reason: '-[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range {10, 9223372036854775797} out of bounds; string length 36'
```

Pls help!

Comment: Put breakpoints in method of `m3u8SegementInfoListValue` (in `NSString+m3u8.h` file, since I guess you are using https://github.com/0dayZh/M3U8Kit ?), and check where it crashes exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make some changes in NSString+m3u8.m:

```
if(NSNotFound != bandwidthRange.location) {
        NSString *value;
    // issue fixed
                if (commaRange.length == 0)
                {
                    value = [substring substringFromIndex:10];

                }
                else
                {
                    value = [substring substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(bandwidthRange.length+1, commaRange.location - (bandwidthRange.length+1))];
                }
        [params setValue:value forKey:keyM3U8SegmentBandwidth];
    }
```

For now i have hard coded the value, you can modify for your requirement.